# How can I place the required asterisk and control in the same line (HTML)?

Tags: html, css, angular

I created a angular dropdown component `"app-ec-dropdown"` using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

```html
<div class="inline required">
  *
</div>
<div class="input-container inline">
  <ng-select 
    class="custom"
    [items]="items"
    bindLabel="Name"
    bindValue="Id"
    (focus)="focus()"
    (close)="close()"
    (clear)="clear()"
    (blur)="blur()"
    placeholder="Select"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedId"
    [required]="required"
  >
  </ng-select>

  <div *ngIf="!validatationPassed()">
    <div class="row alert alert-danger alert-div">
      <span>
        Required field
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS for above component

```css
.input-container {
  width: 95%;
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}

.required {
  vertical-align: top;
  color: red;
  width: 2%;
}
```

Now i am using above component in parent component

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <app-ec-dropdown 
    name="RegionId"
    [items]="regions"
    (onChange)="onRegionChange($event)"
    [selectedId]="state.RegionId"
    [required]="regionDropDownValidator.required"
    [ecDropDownValidator]="regionDropDownValidator"
    [(ngModel)]="regionDropDownValidator.selectedId"
    ngDefaultControl
  > </app-ec-dropdown>
</div>
```

for Region Dropdown, I want red asterisk, to be placed as in "State Name" textbox and then dropdown and validation message in the adjacent div.

Screen grab:

[image: Please click here for screen grab]

Comment: what's in div-control class?

Comment: @Smollet777, i removed div-control class. no difference though. it is .div-control {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

Comment: Could you create a "StackBlitz" with a working piece of your code?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with your code, I thought about the way that I would do it.

I noticed that the actual label isn't included in your example above, so I assume that it's being included within a column to the left of the `<div class="col-sm-4">` element where you're consuming the `<app-ec-dropdown>` component which I assume that you have defined with the first code block.

My advice which will be the easiest and most correct (in my opinion), would be to add the label as an `@Input` property in your code for the `<app-ec-dropdown>` component.

Then you can place it closer to the asterisk character.

So add this to your EcDropdownComponent TypeScript:

```
@Input()
public label: string = '';
```

Then add the input attribute where you consume your component:

```
<app-ec-dropdown 
  name="RegionId"
  [items]="regions"
  label="State Name"
  (onChange)="onRegionChange($event)"
  [selectedId]="state.RegionId"
  [required]="regionDropDownValidator.required"
  [ecDropDownValidator]="regionDropDownValidator"
  [(ngModel)]="regionDropDownValidator.selectedId"
  ngDefaultControl>
</app-ec-dropdown>
```

Then you can use the CSS grid to define the layout within your component:

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- Label -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="label">
      {{label}}
      <span class="inline required"> * </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Select Input -->
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="input-container inline">
      <ng-select
        class="custom"
        [items]="items"
        bindLabel="Name"
        bindValue="Id"
        (focus)="focus.emit()"
        (close)="close.emit()"
        (clear)="clear.emit()"
        (blur)="blur.emit()"
        placeholder="Select"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedId"
        [required]="required">
      </ng-select>

      <div *ngIf="!validatationPassed()">
        <div class="row alert alert-danger alert-div">
      <span>
        Required field
      </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you have a completely self-contained component which doesn't need to worry about anything outside of it's scope.

If you're concerned about variable widths using Bootstrap and the grid system.
You can also pass the grid column style in as an `@Input` property to the component so that you're providing more control to the consuming component.